Compile and run a GoogleTest with CMake and MinGW MSYS2
I want to compile and run a GoogleTest with CMake.
I have followed exactly the instructions from this tutorial
Google Test with CMake
This is the error output that I get (myproject is the directory where the CMakeLists.txt resides as mentioned in the tutorial )
imelf@DESKTOP-CFHKUQA MINGW32 /d/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject
$ mkdir buildmingw

imelf@DESKTOP-CFHKUQA MINGW32 /d/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject
$ cd buildmingw

imelf@DESKTOP-CFHKUQA MINGW32 /d/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw
$ cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Software/MSYS2/usr/bin/cc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Software/MSYS2/usr/bin/cc.exe - works
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Software/MSYS2/usr/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Software/MSYS2/usr/bin/c++.exe - works
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at D:/Software/MSYS2/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1279 (message):
  The DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP option was not given and policy CMP0135 is
  not set.  The policy's OLD behavior will be used.  When using a URL
  download, the timestamps of extracted files should preferably be that of
  the time of extraction, otherwise code that depends on the extracted
  contents might not be rebuilt if the URL changes.  The OLD behavior
  preserves the timestamps from the archive instead, but this is usually not
  what you want.  Update your project to the NEW behavior or specify the
  DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP option with a value of true to avoid this
  robustness issue.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (FetchContent_Declare)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at D:/Software/MSYS2/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/GNUInstallDirs.cmake:243 (message):
  Unable to determine default CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR directory because no
  target architecture is known.  Please enable at least one language before
  including GNUInstallDirs.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  buildmingw/_deps/googletest-src/CMakeLists.txt:28 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found Python: D:/Software/Python/python.exe (found version "3.11.1") found components: Interpreter 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw

imelf@DESKTOP-CFHKUQA MINGW32 /d/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw
$ mingw32-make
[ 10%] Building CXX object _deps/googletest-build/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj
In file included from D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-message.h:55,
                 from D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-assertion-result.h:46,
                 from D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:59,
                 from D:\Informatik\NachhilfeInfoUni\KadalaSchmittC++\poose24test\poose24test\myproject\buildmingw\_deps\googletest-src\googletest\src\gtest-all.cc:38:
D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h: In function ‘int testing::internal::posix::FileNo(FILE*)’:
D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:2018:40: error: ‘fileno’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘FileNo’?
 2018 | inline int FileNo(FILE* file) { return fileno(file); }
      |                                        ^~~~~~
      |                                        FileNo
D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h: In function ‘char* testing::internal::posix::StrDup(const char*)’:
D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:2024:47: error: ‘strdup’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘StrDup’?
 2024 | inline char* StrDup(const char* src) { return strdup(src); }
      |                                               ^~~~~~
      |                                               StrDup
D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h: In function ‘FILE* testing::internal::posix::FDOpen(int, const char*)’:
D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:2074:56: error: ‘fdopen’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘fopen’?
 2074 | inline FILE* FDOpen(int fd, const char* mode) { return fdopen(fd, mode); }
      |                                                        ^~~~~~
      |                                                        fopen
In file included from D:\Informatik\NachhilfeInfoUni\KadalaSchmittC++\poose24test\poose24test\myproject\buildmingw\_deps\googletest-src\googletest\src\gtest-all.cc:45:
D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc: In constructor ‘testing::internal::CapturedStream::CapturedStream(int)’:
D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/poose24test/poose24test/myproject/buildmingw/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc:1102:31: error: ‘::mkstemp’ has not been declared; did you mean ‘mkdtemp’?
 1102 |     const int captured_fd = ::mkstemp(const_cast<char*>(name_template.data()));
      |                               ^~~~~~~
      |                               mkdtemp
mingw32-make[2]: *** [_deps\googletest-build\googletest\CMakeFiles\gtest.dir\build.make:76: _deps/googletest-build/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:215: _deps/googletest-build/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:145: all] Error 2

What do I do wrong?
I also tried to replace the "FetchContent Stuff" in the CMakeLists.txt by Find_Library having installed GoogleTest before with pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtest
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(my_project)

# GoogleTest requires at least C++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_library(GTest gtest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
  hello_test
  hello_test.cc
)
target_link_libraries(
  hello_test
  gtest gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(hello_test)

Then I got the following error:
D:\Informatik\NachhilfeInfoUni\KadalaSchmittC++\poose24test\poose24test\myproject\hello_test.cc:1:10: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <gtest/gtest.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\hello_test.dir\build.make:75: CMakeFiles/hello_test.dir/hello_test.cc.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/hello_test.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:100: all] Error 2


It seems you are confusing find_package(GTest), which locates GTest's headers and libraries, with find_library, which locates only the library file. See e.g. that answer about proper using of find_package for googletest.

Hello Tsyvarev, using find_package instead of find_library helped. But now I get the error with FileNo in gtest-port.h (see my original question). All the best, Florian

So you are building googletest actually. Probably, via GoogleTest,cmake script. Why do you additionally want to find it via find_package? As for the error message, it looks similar to one e.g. in that question.

Thanks a lot! In the link to the question you gave me I found the answer. I had to move the # Setzte verwendeten C++-Standard auf C++17
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17) after the inclusion of GoogleTest

I managed to solve the problem by putting the line
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

after the inclusion of GoogleTest
